# Dreamweaver Auto Collapse Methods/Functions

Tags: dreamweaver, text-editor, code-folding

In Dreamweaver (or in any other text editor), is it possible to automatically collapse, for example, all methods/functions in a class file?  I know it's possible to highlight text and collapse manually, but due to file sharing I always lose my collapses.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not possible in Dreamweaver, the code editor functions are what they are for the most part.  Programmer's Notepad also doesn't do it.  Notepad++ may have a plugin but I'm not 100% certain.